# I want to write a property to application.properties before spring boot application start

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to write a property to application.properties before spring boot application start.

```
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        try {
            properties.load(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/application.properties"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (properties.getProperty("name") == null) {
            OutputStream os = null;
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.setProperty("name", "WriteTheName");
            try {
                os = new FileOutputStream("src/main/resources/application.properties", true);
                prop.store(os, "Dynamic Property File");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Already available Name %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");
        }
```

The above code, i used with CommandLineRunner's run method. This is writing the value after application started.
Please let me know if there is a way to write the property value before application start up.

Comment: why you want upate application properties? Maybe for your use case is better other approche

Comment: My Application requires a property value which is dynamic and has to be written before it's startup.

Comment: can you use env variables for set property?

Comment: can you separate property file for doing dynamic stuff.?

Comment: Even though i will separate the file, it has to be written before startup only, so that it will be available the class where it got injected with @Value annotation.

Comment: I tried putting the property to environment variable. But Application is not able to pick it up. Do i have to specify the property again while running the application as argument?

Comment: Spring Boot uses different locations to load property values from (see [the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config)). Setting it as environment variable or system variable will do. You are making it way to complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the app is built and started, you won't have access to `src/main/resources`.

Writing a properties file after starting an app but before starting to load the Spring context is not a good approach. One of the few use cases I see with this is during an application installation where maybe some random ids would have to be generated but this is the job of the installer and not the job of the application.

Alternatively you can pass property values to a Spring Boot application as:

Assuming the property you would like to use is named: `my.property.key`:

```
java -Dmy.property.key=value -jar application.jar
java -jar application.jar --my.property.key=value
MY_PROPERTY_KEY=value java -jar application.jar
```